# How to load a RTYPES.NILSXP data object when using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, analytics, rpy2

rpy2 allows me to use *some* but not all of the returned values from a function (`dea()`) in `library(Benchmarking)` from R in Python because some of them return RTYPES.NILSXP instead of an ndarray or int. How do I get these data out from RTYPES.NILSXP object?

#### Set-up:

```py
#imports 
import pandas as pd

import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

#helps work with pd.DataFrame objects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter


#import the R library into Python
packnames = ('Benchmarking')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))

Benchmarking = importr('Benchmarking')
base = importr('base')

data = pd.read_csv("path/to_data.csv")

#call the function I want and store it in a variable
with localconverter(robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
  crs = Benchmarking.dea(data['Age'], data['CO2'], RTS='crs', ORIENTATION='in')
```

`crs['eff']` or `crs['lambda']` work fine and return ndarrays

```py
crs
____________________________________________________________________
o{'eff': [1.    0.625 0.5  ], 'lambda': [[1.   0.   0.  ]
 [1.25 0.   0.  ]
 [1.5  0.   0.  ]], 'objval': [1.    0.625 0.5  ], 'RTS': [1] "crs"
, 'primal': <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP], 'dual': <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP], 'ux': <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP], 'vy': <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP], 'gamma': function (x)  .Primitive("gamma")
, 'ORIENTATION': [1] "in"
, 'TRANSPOSE': [1] FALSE
, 'param': <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP], }
```

So far so good.

**However** there is more useful data that I would like to extract eg.

```py
crs['dual']
_______________________________________________________________
<rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP]
```

What kind of object is this? <>

Searching up RTYPES.NILSXP in the 3.5.3 docs takes me to [a page in the docs](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_rpackages.html) which is the only mention I have found.

I have no idea how to read this. The docs explains that datasets can be serialised R objects or serialised R code that produces the dataset. rpy2 employs 'lazy loading' and to load the data, one must use the method `fetch()` but I don't seem to be able to use it correctly to load the rest of the outputs from `dea(x, y, *args)`

### Failed attempts to load data

```py
rpy2.robjects.packages.PackageData.fetch(crs['dual'])
_______________________________________________________________
TypeError: PackageData.fetch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

I've found `fetch()` method belongs to PackageData. I've tried to call it but now it asks me for the 'name' of this dataset?? I thought `crs['dual']` was enough information. When I pass in `'dual'` as the name parameter I get

```
rpy2.robjects.packages.PackageData.fetch(r_from_df_crs['dual'], 'dual')

File ~\anaconda3\envs\UROP_buildings_env\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py:143, in PackageData.fetch(self, name)
    136 def fetch(self, name):
    137     """ Fetch the dataset (loads it or evaluates the R associated
    138     with it.
    139 
    140     In R, datasets are loaded into the global environment by default
    141     but this function returns an environment that contains the dataset(s).
    142     """
--> 143     if self._datasets is None:
    144         self._init_setlist()
    146     if name not in self._datasets:

AttributeError: 'NULLType' object has no attribute '_datasets
```

so I am stuck. How can I deserialise this `<RTYPES.NILSXP>` object from memory?

Edit:

So taking into account @igautier's answer, I've used the `rpackages.data()` method to instantiate the PacketData class and enable access to `.fetch()`

```py
my_crs = rpackages.data(crs)
_________________________________
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 my_crs = rpackages.data(crs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\UROP_buildings_env\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py:522, in data(package)
    520 def data(package):
    521     """ Return the PackageData for the given package."""
--> 522     return package.__rdata__

AttributeError: 'OrdDict' object has no attribute '__rdata__'
```

How can I now convert my 'OrdDict' into PacketData?

---

In a nutshell, the solution was that I had omitted the `SLACK=True` and `DUAL=True` arguments in the `dea()` function and hence the dual and slack results were given as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However there is more useful data that I would like to extract eg.
>
> ```
> crs['dual']
> _______________________________________________________________
> <rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType object at 0x00000220BCB0D1C0> [RTYPES.NILSXP]
> ```
>
> What kind of object is this? <>

This is R's `NULL` object. This is pretty much like a `NULL` in C, or a `null` in Java or Javascript. With the increasing use of Python for data science, `None` came to mean either the equivalent of a `NULL`, or a missing value (which is an `NA` or variant in R). The default conversion is returning an R `NULL` rather than convert to `None` to avoid confusions. This is an early decision though. If the need to revisit this an issue should be opened on the project's page (on Github).

> Searching up RTYPES.NILSXP in the 3.5.3 docs takes me to a page in the docs which is the only mention I have found.

The mention on that page refers to the default value for a named argument:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_rpackages.html#rpy2.robjects.packages.PackageData
I see that the documentation is incomplete. `lib_loc` is an optional path for the class constructor indicating where the R package is installed.

> I have no idea how to read this. The docs explains that datasets can be serialised R objects or serialised R code that produces the dataset. rpy2 employs 'lazy loading' and to load the data, one must use the method fetch() but I don't seem to be able to use it correctly to load the rest of the outputs from dea(x, y, *args)

What is meant here is that "data" objects in R packages are not necessarily serialized R data structures like the R functions `save()`, `dump()`, or `dput()` can help produce. They can also be R scripts. For example, an R package can have a data object "myrandnorm100" that is an R script `data/myrandnorm100.R` in the installed package's directory and that script will be evaluated using the R function `source()` (see https://rdrr.io/r/utils/data.html). That script can define an arbitrary number of variables. Note that serialized R data (for example in an `.RData` file can also contain several named objects). The design choice for `rpy2` was to try make things a little safer and predictable by keeping those names within a namespace. Silent name clashes can be at the root of challenging bugs in code.

(...)

> rpy2.robjects.packages.PackageData.fetch(crs['dual'])
>
> ---
>
> TypeError: PackageData.fetch() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
>
> I've found fetch() method belongs to PackageData. I've tried to call it but now it asks me for the 'name' of this dataset??

Yes. The `PackageData` object is like a namespace with as many named objects as the author of the R package wanted to include.

> I thought `crs['dual']` was enough information. When I pass in 'dual'
> as the name parameter I get
> rpy2.robjects.packages.PackageData.fetch(r_from_df_crs['dual'], 'dual')
>
> ```
> File ~\anaconda3\envs\UROP_buildings_env\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py:143, in PackageData.fetch(self, name)
>     136 def fetch(self, name):
>     137     """ Fetch the dataset (loads it or evaluates the R associated
>     138     with it.
>     139 
>     140     In R, datasets are loaded into the global environment by default
>     141     but this function returns an environment that contains the dataset(s).
>     142     """
> --> 143     if self._datasets is None:
>     144         self._init_setlist()
>     146     if name not in self._datasets:
>
> AttributeError: 'NULLType' object has no attribute '_datasets>
> ```

Well, this is not how `DataPackage` objects can be instanciated. I'll use the R package `datasets` as an example since it is part of the R standard library.

```
# Import the R package "datasets"
datasets = importr('datasets')
# That package only contains datasets. The Python object will look
# like it has no (useful) attributes. We can create an instance
# for the data in the package with:
datasets_data = rpackages.data(datasets)
# All dataset names are available through `datasets_data.names()`.
# We know the name of the one we want.
mtcars_env = datasets_data.fetch('mtcars')
# mtcars_env is an R "environment", wrapped as an `rpy2.robjects.Environment`
```

Note: I am seeing now that the doc has that information, but available throughout scattered examples rather also on the page about packages (see
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/search.html?q=data+fetch).

However, what you have here is **not** an R package dataset. Your object
`crs` is the result of calling a function:

> ```
> crs = Benchmarking.dea(data['Age'], data['CO2'],
>                        RTS='crs', ORIENTATION='in')
> ```

There is likely no element named `"dual"` in `crs`, which a look at the documentation for that function seems to confirm.

Comment: Hi so I see that ```rpackages.data()``` extracts the PacketData which then allows me to call the ```fetch('dual')``` but then I receive the error ```AttributeError: 'OrdDict' object has no attribute '__rdata__'
``` I will update my question to show this

Comment: What you have is not a package dataset. I added a final paragraph to the answer.

Comment: You were correct - I omitted the parameters: SLACK=True, DUAL=True which meant that the 'dual' variable was not calculated/given as null

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom converter for it:

```py
my_converter = robjects.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter

@local_rules.rpy2py.register(rinterface.NULLType)
def rpy2py_null(obj):
    return None

with localconverter(my_converter):
  crs = Benchmarking.dea(data['Age'], data['CO2'], RTS='crs', ORIENTATION='in')
```